# Install windows updates along with PXE install

Tags: windows, windows-update, pxe-boot, sysprep

Here is the problem.  I do testing..  I need windows, not by choice, for testing purposes.  I need physical hardware to do my testing. To do this, I install windows from PXE.  The problem with this is, that I now need to have all of the windows updates installed after windows is done installing.  HOWEVER, windows updates take A VERY LONG TIME.  Like 6 hours+ to install (Downloading only takes seconds) as well as multiple reboots. Instead of installing the updates every time I finish a PXE install which is very time consuming, is there a way to get windows to install the updates, maybe even from wndows PE to speed up the process of updating? I've already looked into making a generalized sys-prep image, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the sys-prepped image install like standard windows and I don't want to have to reconfigure my entire pxe configuration to use clone-zilla to mirror the sysprepped image.  Is there a way to make a sysprepped image that will work with setup.exe?

Comment: Is it possible to update your "golden image" with the Windows Updates so every time you install Windows, it comes with the updates already installed?

Comment: In sys-prep, you can make a golden image that has the updates and even applications already installed. The problem then becomes licensing and deployment of that sysprepped windows image.  I'm wondering if there is a better way than having to engineer an entirely different way of deploying windows by throwing down sysprepped windows using DD from clonezilla. If there was a way to make a sysprepped image that gets installed using the setup.exe included in the windows .iso, that would be stellar.  However, I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: A method in which all of the updates were bundled and installed from a single installer in less than an hour would also be acceptable, but that is probably asking for too much.